# Distance estimate from implicit surface

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

This is about understanding the distance to an offset surface of an implicit surface. This has industrial applications.

Consider a 3D implicit surface $f(x,y,z)=0$ which is reasonably smooth. Furthermore, assume that the function $f(x,y,z)$ is reasonably smooth in the vicinity of the surface $f(x,y,z)=0$. Now, say that you can evaluate derivatives only on a second surface $f(x,y,z)=C$, where $C$ is a given constant so that this surface is not too far away from the original surface. This means, for example, that we can compute the gradient $\nabla f$, mean curvature $H_1$, and Gaussian curvature $H_2$ at any point on $f(x,y,z)=C$.

Assume we have a point $(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ so that $f(x_1,y_1,z_1)=C$ . Further, assume that there is a $d$ such that $(x_1,y_1,z_1)-\mathbf{n}d = (x_0,y_0,z_0)$ where $\mathbf n$ is the surface normal at $(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ and $f(x_0,y_0,z_0)=0$.

Is there a best, or at least very good, estimator using $\nabla f$, $H_1$, and $H_2$ on this second surface at $(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ to estimate this approximate shortest distance $d$ "back" to the surface $f(x,y,z)=0$.

It is assumed here that the isosurfaces of $f(x,y,z)$ are "reasonably parallel" for small deviations from $f(x,y,z)=0$.

Comment: "Best" in what sense? Without a metric, it's very hard to optimize. The analogous question in 1D is this: suppose $f(0) = 0$, and $f'(0)$ and $f''(0)$ are known. What's the best estimate of a point $a$ near zero where $f (a) = C$? As you can easily see, if $f$ is polynomial, $a$ can be anywhere. If $f$ is of the form $f(x) = K + Le^x$, then ... well, $a$ can again be anywhere, but ... *differently*. And if $f$ is periodic with period 1, for instance, then $a$ can only be between $-1$ and $1$. We really need a notion of "best" (or a prior on the distribution from which $f$ is drawn).

Comment: @JohnHughes I see. Thanks. I will have to clarify.

Comment: @JohnHughes I think I may have clarified it now.